No wifi after wake from suspend Ubuntu 24.04
After upgrading to 24.04 from 23.10, I lose wifi after a wake from suspend. Restarting brings it back. This problem is new with 24.04. Had no problems with 23.10.
lspci-v gives:
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200NGW
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Memory at fce00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

Wired internet connectivity isn't affected.

This also happens in ubuntu 22.4 especially when the cpu gets overloaded and the computer crashes and restart. The easiest way to solve the problem is to restart your computer
